# Symfony2 - Doctrine : edit repository directory path when creating new entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using **DoctrineBundle** along with **SensioGeneratorBundle** for my Symfony project.

When I create an entity with the php command :

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

It does the job fine because it matches my project organization, but it doesn't for **the entity's repository**:

```
project_name
│   index.php
└───Application <-- generated but it shouldn't 
    └───Repository
        |  MyEntityRepository.php
│
└───app
    └───Controllers
    └───Migrations
    └───Entity
        |  MyEntity.php
    └───Repository <-- Entity's repository must be here
```

By the way my composer.json's namespace configuration is the following :

```
"autoload" : {
  "psr-0":{
      "Application\\":"app/"
  }
  "psr-4":{
      "Application\\":"app/"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to edit the Repository directory's path, like for the migrations one ?

```
doctrine_migrations:
  dir_name: "%kernel.project_dir%/app/Migrations"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: couldn´t you just use it like `doctrine:generate:entity appBundle:Foo`

Comment: @johnSmith That's exactly what I typed to get that issue with the repository directory